# ignoring subdirectories using gitignore and ignore files in general

Tags: gitignore, ignore

Say I want to ignore node_modules, but also node_modules for subdirectories:

```
project/
   node_modules
   bar/
     node_modules
   foo/
     node_modules
   baz/
     node_modules
   .gitignore
```

what do I need to put in my .gitignore file too ignore all node_modules folders?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `git` uses patterns from `.gitignore` to match content in sub-folders recursively. So, putting the following content into `.gitignore` is enough.

```
node_modules/
```

If your folder `node_modules` has been added into the repo already. You need to untrack them.

```sh
git rm --cached node_modules
```